# Do I need to submit for facebook app review?

Tags: ios, facebook

I am developing iOS app with Facebook share function.
I am ONLY using Login and Share function of Facebook SDK.
In this case, do I need to submit for facebook app review?

(I am asking this question here because there seems to be no help contact in Facebook developer site)

Thanks.

Comment: If you are not asking for any permissions that need review - then no ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review/faqs

> Your app can use Facebook Login to access public_profile, email and user_friends without submitting for review.

Comment: Thanks for your anwer!

Comment: you are welcome, please do not forget to accept my answer.